# Can I delete the e from catch block of try-catch?

Tags: c#, .net, exception, try-catch

```
catch (HttpAntiForgeryException e)
{
    throw new HttpAntiForgeryException("Forgery Exception");
}
```

When I build the project, there is a warning said: The variable 'e' is declared but never used.
Is that because the e is not necessary?

Comment: It's a very bad practice. If you want to replace some exception with your own, pass this exception as `InnerException`. If you won't do this, you'll loose information about root cause of *your* exception.

Comment: That warning appears whenever there is a variable that is declared but never used. That warning is just that - a warning. That by itself is not indicative of whether that variable is actually useful. (In this case, it really is.)

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You can just simply write

```
catch (HttpAntiForgeryException)
{
    throw new HttpAntiForgeryException("Forgery Exception");
}
```

But, you are rethrowing same type of exception. You can also simply delete this catch block.

Comment: The exception content differs.

Comment: @C4u Differ and less detailed. It's acceptable to rethrow if you add some detail into message.

Answer (score 2):

It is no necessary if you don't want to do anything with the exception, in your case you are throwing custom message so its fine to use like this :

```
catch 
{
   throw new HttpAntiForgeryException("Forgery Exception");
}
```

or like this :

```
// For specific exception
catch (HttpAntiForgeryException)
{
       throw new HttpAntiForgeryException("Forgery Exception");
}
```

But you will not get any information regarding this exception, like error message, stack-Trace, inner exception etc.. I prefer you to handle the exception in Catch, Or [properly log](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff664711(v=pandp.50).aspx) them for developer's reference

Answer (score 2):

It's because You have not used the Variable e within any where of the catch block. You can easily catch that exception so you will get better understanding of the root cause of your exception than throwing a new exception.

```
catch (HttpAntiForgeryException e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.Message); // Console.Writeline or whichever way you want      
}
```